# How to INSERT days to keep a MYSQL calendar table current?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, insert

I have a `calendar` table in my MYSQL database with one field named `datefield` (type `DATE`).

Previously I inserted dates from 2008-01-01 to 2010-01-01 but now I want to add every day until the current date. Unfortunately, I'm completely forgotten how I did this.

I'm also wondering if there is any way to automate the process of keeping this table current.

I'm using PHP so I guess I could do a new `INSERT` every day? Or is there some way to do this directly in MYSQL?

thanks,
tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick hack:

```
drop table if exists dates;
create table dates(datefield date);


drop procedure if exists insertDates;

delimiter $$
create procedure insertDates(start_date date)
begin
set @days = 0;
set @end_date = str_to_date('1970-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d');

while (@end_date < curdate()) do
insert into dates
select
date_add(start_date, interval @days day)
from (select @days:=@days+1) r
;
set @end_date:=(select max(datefield) from dates);
end while
;

end $$

delimiter ;

call insertDates('2012-06-06');

select * from dates;
```

For the daily insert you can try a cron job or MySQL offers "EVENTS", something like:

```
CREATE EVENT yourDB_Schema.insertDateEachDay
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
INSERT INTO yourTable (yourDateColumn) VALUES (CURDATE());
```

Read more about it here:

[MySQL Create Event manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

> An event is associated with a schema. If no schema is indicated as
>   part of event_name, the default (current) schema is assumed.

_

> Not specifying STARTS is the same as using STARTS
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP—that is, the action specified for the event begins
>   repeating immediately upon creation of the event.

Comment: -@tombom, awesome!!! so how many days does this insert? from 1970 until today? Also, for the mysql "EVENT", can you explain a little more on what the "INSERT" would look like? That is precisely what I don't understand.

Comment: The start date in this case is '2012-06-15', change it to whatever you like. The date '1970-01-01' is just a random date prior to the current date. The procedure once created inserts when called one day into table dates for each date between '2012-06-15' and the current date. Replace like you wish or add a parameter for start date.

Comment: The INSERT for CREATE EVENT would be `INSERT INTO yourTable (yourDateColumn) VALUES (CURDATE())`

Comment: I can explain more if you wish later, but I have to watch soccer first :)

Comment: thanks, awesome, yeah i need to figure out the `@` symbol equivalent in MYSQL cause your command is throwing errors, have fun!

Comment: here's the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create procedure insertDates()
begin
set @days = 0;
set @end_date = '1970-01-01'' at line 2`

Comment: @timpeterson Reviewed the code and added start date as parameter. Works fine for me.

Comment: hmm, i had to eliminate this: `drop procedure if exists insertDates;` cause got an error saying "insertDates doesn't exist". After that, the `Dates` table was created, but there are no values in it. I just copied your code directly so not sure what the problem is...

Comment: There seems to be something really strange, cause the "if exists" in the line you eliminated prevents the error "insertDates doesn't exist" to pop up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12926/discussion-between-tombom-and-tim-peterson)

Comment: -@tombom, so I created the `insertDateEachDay` EVENT but it didn't add today's date. After creating this event, do I need to call it somehow such that event actually happens?

Comment: @timpeterson Edited my answer, included parts of manual that may cause the error. And I have to ask, was the computer on and mysql server running? Missed events are not repeated. If that's not it, have a look in the logs, if you can see why the event didn't trigger.

Comment: yes, the computer was on and the mysql server is running. hmm, I need to find the logs and don't know what my db.schema is, this is all new territory for me...

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do what you describe is set up a daily recurring task to run a php script, such as a cron job. There is also a web based provider that will call a script from your webserver on a cheap, recurring schedule. http://webcron.org